# logical operators in if statements c++

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, logical-operators

The current code at the bottom works but I can't combine the if statements without shifting the ascii values to a position that I don't want them to be. The encryption is supposed to be only alphabet values. Capital and lowercase z's are supposed to loop around to an A. I have a teacher but she doesn't know so I would be grateful for any help. Thanks <3

This doesn't work...

```
if (sentence[i] == 'z' || 'Z')
{
sentence[i] = sentence[i] - 26;
}
```

And this doesn't work

```
if (sentence[i] == 'z' || sentence[i] == 'Z')
{
sentence[i] = sentence[i] - 26;
}
```

This works.

```
if (sentence[i] == 'z')
{
sentence[i] = sentence[i] - 26;
}
if (sentence[i] == 'Z')
{
sentence[i] = sentence[i] - 26;
}
```

Full code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class EncryptionClass
{
    string sentence;

public:

    //constructors
    EncryptionClass(string sentence)
        {setString(sentence);}
    EncryptionClass()
        {sentence = "";}

    //get and set
    string getString()
        {return sentence;}
    void setString(string sentence)
        {this-> sentence = sentence;}

    //encrypt
    void encryptString()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
        {
            if (isalpha(sentence[i]))
            {

                if (sentence[i] == 'z')
                {
                    sentence[i] = sentence[i] - 26;
                }
                if (sentence[i] == 'Z')
                {
                    sentence[i] = sentence[i] - 26;
                }

                sentence[i] = sentence[i] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    string sentence;
    cout << "Enter a sentence to be encrypted. ";
    getline(cin, sentence);
    cout << endl;

    EncryptionClass sentence1(sentence);
    cout << "Unencrypted sentence." << endl;
    cout << sentence1.getString() << endl << endl;
    sentence1.encryptString();
    cout << "Encrypted sentence." << endl;
    cout << sentence1.getString() << endl;


    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your claim the second "doesn't work"  [doesn't hold water](http://ideone.com/GdA4wu).

Comment: what happens when you try `if (sentence[i] == 'z' || sentence[i] == 'Z')` that makes you say it does not work?

Comment: @slawekwin I'm getting an error when I try it on my compiler. "lvalue required as left operand on assignment."

Comment: The full code you posted compiles and runs properly for me, even when I replace the `if` with the *second* example you posted.

Answer (score 1):

In your case both If statements should both be equally.

```
if (sentence[i] == 'z' || sentence[i] == 'Z')
{
    sentence[i] = sentence[i] - 26;
}
```

And:

```
if (sentence[i] == 'z')
{
    sentence[i] = sentence[i] - 26;
}
if (sentence[i] == 'Z')
{
    sentence[i] = sentence[i] - 26;
}
```

**This is not always the case**.

Snippet 2: if you change the value if `i` or `sentence[i]`, the 2nd `if` will behave different.
If you would decrement by value 32, then both snippets will behave different

```
char myChar = 'z'
if (myChar == 'z' || myChar == 'Z')
{
    myChar = myChar - 32;
}
// myChar is now 'Z'
```

And:

```
char myChar = 'z'
if (myChar == 'z')
{
    myChar = myChar - 32;
}
// myChar is now 'Z'
if (myChar == 'Z')
{
    myChar = myChar - 32;
}
// myChar is now ':'
```

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I was talking about the if-statement in general. Obviously it would behave different if you change the value of i...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Correct changing sentence[i] has the same effect as changing i. In this scenario, the OP is decrementing the value with 26. Which changes the value z to `. So clearly this has no effect for his scenario. I've updated my answer with pitfall.

Comment: Yeah I thought they would behave the same but when I use the combined if statement I get some random ascii value. Usually { regardless of how much I decrement. Or I'll get an error "lvalue required as left operand" so there's a better way to do the comparison I'm guessing but I don't know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you should be deducting **`25`** from your value, not **`26`**! That's because there are 26 letters in the alphabet, relatively numbered from `0` to `25` (inclusive). To arrive at the first letter (number `0`) from the last letter (number `25`) you need to deduct **`25`**.

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

But every version except the first version should give the same results.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char sentance[] = "Zz";

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        if(sentance[i] == 'Z' || sentance[i] == 'z')
        {
            sentance[i] = sentance[i] - 25;
            std::cout << "letter " << i << " = " << sentance[i] << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

**[Run it here](https://ideone.com/j2ZJa9)**

Comment: This assumes that the representation of letters of the alphabet in the compiler's encoding are contiguous and increasing. There are character encodings for which that is not true.

Comment: @PeteBecker Very true. But those encodings are unlikely to be used in a basic student exercise like this. So I would prefer not to complicate the example. Also, the question does specify `ASCII` encoding.

Comment: Teaching people basic things that are wrong isn't helpful. Granted, there are more complicated things that demand simplification, but understanding the basics of character sets isn't one of them. Writing this code portably isn't that hard. Aside: I suspect that that passing mention of "ascii" isn't part of the requirements, but an assumption on the part of the coder.

Comment: @PeteBecker What is not helpful is confusing beginners with irrelevant information that they didn't ask for and is likely way above their level.  The question is not about various character encodings. Its a basic exercise in encrypting `ASCII` data. It would take me 1000s of words to explain character sets to someone who barely understands `ASCII`. Given that the teacher has tried to solve this problem I am sure that `ASCII` is part of the **requirements**. This is a basic exercise that **all** students get at some point.

Comment: No, it's simple to say "note that this assumes that the program is using the ASCII character encoding. While that's quite common, be warned that there are other character encodings, and on a system that doesn't use ASCII your code might not work correctly."

Comment: @PeteBecker The `OP` just wants to know why their math doesn't work on `ASCII` codes. That's all. I don't think it is useful to potentially confuse people with information that is not relevant to the question. That can really turn students off. Do we embark on a discussion about character encodings with every question that deals with simple text processing? Do we warn people about `BOM` every time they open a file? `IMO` its a separate issue for a question that doesn't rely on the specified encoding or where the specified encoding might be the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: You're right: you should never go outside the bounds of the question that was asked. After all, the person who asked the question always knows exactly what they need.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm really not *trying* to be difficult. This did occur to me when I wrote the answer. But I made an *active decision* to avoid introducing a discussion about other character encodings. Specifically because when you are learning about them, computers can seem fairly daunting. Learning that they are even more complicated than you already think they are can be discouraging. I think that's the right call on questions that are obviously from beginners. I understand if you disagree.

Comment: @Galik Yeah I added +1 to every character and I only subtracted from the z values. So it goes to an 'A' it's just without using if statements because I couldn't figure out why the code wasn't working. Still can't. But apparently this is off discussion? I thought it was pretty clear. :\

Comment: @cba1067950 I suggest you edit your question to include a **complete** piece of code that shows what you are doing and produces the error you describe. What you described here sounds like: `if(ch == 'z' || ch == 'Z') ch = ch - 25; else ch = ch + 1;`.